# Can 2 processes run on same enclave in intel sgx?

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, intel, sgx

I know intel sgx supports running multiple threads on one enclave. But I'curious that whether I can use fork to run 2 processes on one enclave?

Comment: This depends on your definition of a "process". Do you want separate address spaces or not?

Comment: CPUs don't support processes. At all. They're something made up by software. So the answer is yes. You can make them up in software inside your enclave code.

Comment: @user253751: Hardware support is necessary to give separate address-spaces, the difference between a thread and process.  (Part of) the question is whether the HW supports two separate address-spaces using SGX.  I don't know a lot about SGX, but IDK how they might communicate with each other directly inside the same enclave if they don't share memory, though.  Would there be a meaningful differences between the unsupported thing of two separate address-spaces in one enclave vs. two processes using separate enclaves?  Maybe that would be meaningful if it were supported, IDK.

Comment: @PeterCordes another artificial distinction; systems without memory protection may still be said to have processes (without memory protection). The actual distinction between a thread and a process seems to be the level of co-operation.

Comment: @user253751: Part of the point of SGX is isolation; it hardly seems like an artificial distinction.

Answer (score 1):

**What you cannot do**: have more that 1 **program** (or process) to use an enclave. Only the process that has created the enclave can use it.

**What you can do**: have more that 1 **thread** inside an enclave, but you have to create them in the untrusted part of the app. In your XML enclave config file there are 2 values, `TCSNum` and `TCSPolicy`.

For more information, see [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Software-Guard-Extensions/Intel-SGX-Threading-and-vs-TCS/td-p/1069371) and [here](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel_sgx_sdk_developer_reference_for_linux_os_pdf.pdf).